# jQuery inject into iframe with special HTML syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Looking for a way to select the greater than and less than syntax characters (">" and "<") of an iframe and replace them with some text. Here's where I'm at thus far, a simple input box whose content is auto-injected into an iframe:

**The HTML:**

```
        <div class="desc-input">
            <form>
                <h2>Input Box</h2>
                <textarea></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="html-preview">
            <h2>Text Auto Inserted Here</h2>
            <div class="amazonHtml grid">
                <iframe></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**The jQuery:**

```
        (function() {

        var frame = $('iframe'),
            contents = frame.contents(),
            body = contents.find('body');

            $('textarea').focus(function() {
                var $this = $(this);

            // To live update the preview box
            $this.keyup(function() {    
                body.text( $this.val() );

        });     
      });
    })();
```

[Here's a JSfiddle of the above.](http://jsfiddle.net/SkpzC/2/)

Essentially I'm looking for a way to find and replace all ">" and "<" that could be entered into the text area, as I plan to turn this simple text area into a WYSIWYG input area and need users to be able to see and copy the output HTML, only it's not standard HTML, it's one that needs a slightly different syntax.

Grateful for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to remove all the `<` and `>` you would do:

```
str.replace(/[<>]/g, '');
```

So in your case, it would be:

```
body.text( $this.val().replace(/[<>]/g, '') );
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Glad it helped you :). Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia